# laravel : can't I use enctype='multipart/form-data' to POST non file inputs?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-4

**For some reason if I use POST instead of GET in my .ajax call it doesn't reach the Controller.**

From what I read multipar/form-data can send non-file inputs as well, hence this should work.
I've tried a number of variations and it doesn't work, and now I'm curious as a dog seeing a mirror for the first time !

*Here is the code*

Here is my **Form** which I've cut down to the bare bones :

```
<form id="forward-post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <input type="hidden" value="{{$post->id}}" name="val[postid]" />
    <button class="post-forward-button" class="btn btn-sm btn-success" id="post-submit-button"><i class="icon ion-compose"></i> Forward</button>
</form>
```

Here is the **Javascript** function being called :

```
$(document).on('submit', '#forward-person', function (e)
    {
        e.preventDefault(); // To prevent page refresh after ajax call
        $.ajax({
            url : baseUrl + 'post/forward',
            type : 'POST',
            data : new FormData(this),
            contentType : false,
            cache : false,
            processData : false,
            success : function(data) {
                console.log('Success function of the ajax call');
            }
        });
    });
```

**Controller**

public function forward()
{
    Log::info('Inside forward()');
    if (\Input::has('val'))
    {
        Log::info('Val found');
    }
    return 0;
}

The **route** and everything works for GET, but I'm posting it here again, for completion sake :

```
Route::get('forward', [
        'uses' => 'App\Controllers\PostController@forward'
        ]);
```

I also noticed that when I'm doing a GET, the controller doesn't find 'val' in the Input.
Any clue, what I'm doing incorrectly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since it is making ajax post request, your route has to be

```
Route::post('forward', [
   'uses' => 'App\Controllers\PostController@forward'
]);
```